# How to get parameters from a URL and use them in a MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables, url

So, I will have a page where a user lands with a `/?ref=123` type ending on the URL.
Then, what I want to achieve, is to use that ref `123` in a MySQL query, like this:
`SELECT foo FROM table WHERE table.ref = 123`

The issue I have hit is that if i use `$_GET` to get the variable, it breaks my SQL query (obviously!)

`SELECT foo FROM table WHERE table.ref = $_GET['ref'];` falls over because `$_GET` is not a MySQL function.

Trouble is, I want to dynamically create page content based on the `ref` value but I can't figure how.

Any help gratefully accepted.

Timezone GMT+13 so replies will potentially be slow :)

**********EDIT**********

As I may not have given enough info in the OP, here's the code I'm struggling with:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include "../../../wp-config.php";

$get_donation_amount = "select SUM(amount) AS total_donations from SaveContactForm7_1 where ref = 123 ";
$get_donation_amount_result = $wpdb->get_results($get_donation_amount);
$total_donation = isset($get_donation_amount_result[0]->total_donations) && $get_donation_amount_result[0]->total_donations !="" ? $get_donation_amount_result[0]->total_donations :"0" ;
?>
```

What I need to do is add a call to the URL for the value of `ref` and add it where shown with the SQL querycode. Then a particular donor who knows his 'ref' value will see results relevant to him alone.

Comment: Please take to time to read any of the existing "getting started" tutorials about programming based on php and mysql. They _all_ explain and demonstrate what you ask. And make sure to understand the dangers in that. Learn about the benefits of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding".

Comment: thanks @arkascha - I tried a couple and got rather lost so came here to my old favourite SO. I'll keep Googling....

Comment: "They all explain and demonstrate what you ask" ?? not ww3schools, lynda.com, not freewebmasterhelp, not tutorialspoint (although a very good reference on the related topics) nor mysqltutorial. So far, that's the first two pages of Google results. Would you care to post a link to the tutorial that covers getting a variable from the url and inserting it into a php MySql query string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is impressive. So no tutorial you could find explains how to use `$_GET`? How to concatenate a string to be used as a SQL statement executed as any other SQL statement in the existing database connection you have? _Really_? Although _all_ such tutorials show exactly that? Sorry, but it looks as if you either are not really following any tutorials or you are simply not willing to understand what you are shown. Of course you can use a variable in an SQL query (whether you should is another question). What you yourself posted _will_ work if done correctly (you do not show how you use it).

Comment: Again, thanks, but which tutorial shows me what you describe? I've just now tried searching for $_GET and for "How to concatenate a string to be used as a SQL statement executed as any other SQL statement in the existing database connection you have" and all I get is disjointed bits of results. If I could find what I was looking for, I would not be asking this on SO. Please recommend one such tutorial that is covered by your "Although *all* such tutorials show exactly that?" - I in my confused state cannot find one, or as you put it cannot understand what I am being shown.

Comment: *"What you yourself posted will work if done correctly (you do not show how you use it)."* - I need to get the variable called `$total_donation` to be the sum of only those results that match the URL ref. It is then used in a google chart visualization object to display a progress meter. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP7 this could look something like this

```
$ref = $_GET['ref'] ?? null;

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT foo FROM table WHERE table.ref = ?');
$sth->execute([$ref]);

$orders = $sth->fetchAll();
```

---

You should probably have some way of handling errors (ref is not set)

Note that the last variable (result of the query) is called orders. I didn't know what the result set you expected would be, but it was just to illustrate that it makes sense to call it something spesific (what it actually represents), instead of "rows", "result" or similar.

---

Note that PHP 7 introduces the so called null coalescing operator which simplifies isset statements

PHP7

```
$ref = $_GET['ref'] ?? null;
```

PHP < 7

```
$ref = isset($_GET['ref']) ? $_GET['ref']: null;
```

Comment: It's on PHP 5.5.9. I tried to add your code but no success.

Comment: Maybe I should post more detail? I didn't want to confuse the question, and thus earn downvotes :)

Comment: No. The page simply doesn't render at all.

Comment: @Bevan then you haven't set your development environment to show all errors. A blank page is the default configuration for 500 internal server errors, when developing locally you will want to show all errors

Comment: I'm going to accept yours as the best answer: I upgraded to php7 and your code worked. The page is not working properly, but you answered the question as asked.